# .NET Regex Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: c#, python, .net, regex

I am trying to translate a regex from Python to C#, but i am having some problems as i keep getting the error Unrecognized grouping construct.

```
^(?:\[(?P<release_group>.+?)\][ ._-]*)
(?P<series_name>.+?)[ ._-]+
(?P<ep_ab_num>\d{1,3})
(-(?P<extra_ab_ep_num>\d{1,3}))?[ ._-]+?
(?:v(?P<version>[0-9]))?
(?:[\w\.]*)
(?:(?:(?:[\[\(])(?P<extra_info>\d{3,4}[xp]?\d{0,4}[\.\w\s-]*)(?:[\]\)]))|(?:\d{3,4}[xp]))
(?:[ ._]?\[(?P<crc>\w+)\])?
.*?
```

What is giving me the error Unrecognized grouping construct in this regex?

Comment: Remove the `P`s from `(?P<`

Comment: p.s. you've got loads of unnecessary non-capturing groups (I count 5). Avoiding wrapping something in brackets is exactly the same as putting something in a non-capturing group - but a lot less messy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(?P<groupname>...)` becomes `(?<groupname>...)` in .NET regexes. Just remove the `P`. Same semantics.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Comment: Are these differences documented somewhere? It seems that `(?R)` also doesn't work in .NET...